# recognizing button presses in actionscript

Tags: actionscript, button

In a mini flash game, I have a few different level select buttons, and they all attach to one "levelChange()" function, and I'm just wondering if there is an attribute that stores which button was pressed or how to determine which was pressed if not.

Thanks

Comment: You might clarify, are you doing this in Actionscript 3, or 2? Also, if you are doing it in 2, are you attaching the script directly to a button? I'll provide an answer for AS3, but it may not be helpful if this question is about AS2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the `currentTarget` property of `MouseEvent` example:

```
function buttonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     trace(event.currentTarget);
}
```

I recommend you store your buttons in variables outside your function like so:

```
var levelOne:MovieClip = levelOne;
```

So you can later call upon them like this:

```
function buttonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     if (event.currentTarget == levelOne) {
          trace("level one selected");
     else if (event.currentTarget == levelTwo) {
          trace("level two selected");
     }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote except you're using an IF statement instead of switch.

Comment: @DustinSparks you searched for the name against the instance name which Sam couldn't get to work and I felt that `currentTarget` should be highlighted. At the end of the day Sam found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AS3 you can add a switch statement in your levelChange() function.

For example.... if you have 2 buttons, one with the instance name of "level1", and the other "level2".

```
function levelChange( me:MouseEvent ):void
{
   switch( me.currentTarget.name )
   {
      case "level1":
        // Go to Level 1 here.
      case "level2":
        // Go to Level 2 here. 
   }
}
```

Comment: hmm, it didn't seem to work.  No syntax errors, but the buttons aren't functioning